# Page is not updating url or source code in chrome's dev tool when navigating the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

### Goal

I'm making a Chrome extension to perform some manipulations on my university's website since the layout to select a course is bad. For this I need to access elements to read their inner information and also copy their CSS to add certain information that I will obtain from a different site, in a way that fits the style of the page.

### Problem

When I open the source code on the exact page I want to use, it doesn't display the correct HTML. Instead it shows the main page's code under the dev tool. The interesting part is that when I highlight a certain element the code shows up and I'm able to make changes within the tool. But if I try to call a specific element under the console using `$(id)` or `$$(id)` it would show either `null` or `[]`.

This causes some problems to because I'm new to any sort of web-related development and I would like to see the complete source so that I can select the elements I want and manipulate the page the way I would like. Maybe there is something I'm overlooking? that's why I need your help.

### Possible reasons

I tried many things and try to research and concluded that it might have to do with frames since the url is not changing. However I'm not able to find any resources to teach me about frames (I know nothing about it) if that's the actual problem.

If the problem is another I would appreciate any assistance in solving it or any work around that I am not aware of.

Comment: If you are "new to any sort of web-related development" then do not try manipulate your university's website...

Comment: @marekful why not? Serious question. It allows me to learn and at the same time I could create something useful not only for me but for other students. I don't think it's illegal to make local changes to any page

Comment: OK, I didn't mean to discourage you, but it felt like you're trying to do something you shouldn't.

Comment: @marekful Oh, no sorry about the confusion. I'm just changing the layout for readibilty and adding course description from the school's course catalogue

Answer (score 0):

The reason is definitely the use of frames. There are multiple documents at play here, the top level document and each frame has it's own document. This is important because the JavaScript you are executing is 99.9999% the top level document and not a child frame's document. Due to this, it's not finding the DOM nodes because it doesn't search the frames' documents.

Comment: I see, so I need to somehow access those child frames to those specific elements I need?                                                                      Is there a standard way to do this or do you know of any resources I could use to learn this. Or perhaps these frames are not accessible?

Comment: Once you get the reference of the frame, you can then access it's window and document.